# cant access node server over the internet

Tags: node.js, server, window, restify

I have a basic restify node application.

It's running on a dedicated windows server with a static IP address.
This server was set up by a 3rd party. The firewall has been configured to forward port 8000 to this server.

I can access this node-restify server locally fine.

I have setup rules on the windows firewall to allow incoming and outgoing TCP traffic through port 8000

Here is my server create and listen code:

```
var server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(8000,'0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

When using [localtunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel) I can access the server fine.

What I'm trying to figure out is where my problem resides. Is it my node-restify configuration that's causing this issue or is it the configuration of the windows server by the 3rd party business.